# django making methods with variables avaiable from different files

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

This may be a simple question, but I am really stuck on the issue.

I have been trying to teach myself how to make methods in a views.py file available in other files.

I have a views.py file, where there are several methods like so:

```
def get_available_language_details(language_versions, user_language_code):
.......

def language_versions_compare(x, y):
.......

def get_language_versions(user):
......
```

In my education.py file, I realize I must have an import statement from the views.py file, but I don't know how to write the syntax of the import statement as well as the syntax to call the methods above in the education.py file:

```
import appname.core.views import ??
```

**EDIT**
here is my directory structure:

```
appname
    __init__.py
    core
        __init__.py
        views.py
    views
        __init__.py
        education.py
```

Comment: These are functions, not methods right?

Answer (score 1):

```
from appname.core.views import <function_name>
```

So it would be something like

```
from appname.core.views import language_versions_compare
```

Comment: Bansal Utkarsh, thanks but I get an error when I try your solution: `from appname.core.views import get_available_language_details
ImportError: cannot import name get_available_language_details`

Comment: tell me your complete directory structure, or do you have it on github?

Comment: Bansal Utkarsh, I have added the directory structure in the op.

Comment: you need to add a blank `__init__.py` file in your core directory and another one in the root directory i.e. appname

Comment: there is, i left them out for convience

Comment: So you have a `__init__.py` in all your directories?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95104/discussion-between-bansal-utkarsh-and-user3354539).